# Testing for null $.cookie()

Tags: jquery, cookies

Weird question regarding cookies in jQuery. I have the following:

```
console.log("ShowMoveItems() : " + $.cookie('selectedmoveitems'));
console.log("ShowMoveItems() ISNULL : " + $.cookie('selectedmoveitems') === null);
```

with the following output in Firefox's console:

```
"ShowMoveItems() : null"
false
```

For interest's sake, I have also tried `== null` and it has the same result as `===null`. Why is this the case when `"ShowMoveItems() : " + $.cookie('selectedmoveitems')` shows the cookie as null?

UPDATE afer comment from @RohanKumar:

```
console.log("ShowMoveItems() : ")
console.log($.cookie('selectedmoveitems'));
console.log("ShowMoveItems() ISNULL : ");
console.log($.cookie('selectedmoveitems') === null);

"ShowMoveItems() : "
null
"ShowMoveItems() ISNULL : "
true
```

Comment: For proper debugging, you should pass stuff to `console.log()` using different arguments, rather than concatenating everything into a string. You should also use parenthesis when composing logical expressions. Last but not least, `$.cookie` is not part of standard jQuery but most likely a plug-in; it never hurts to mention which one.

Comment: `false`! I think it should be `ShowMoveItems() ISNULL : false` in the second `log message`

Comment: @RohanKumar you are right, the plugin is from [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Thanks for the advice regarding regarding console debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When casting to string, you get `"null"` when you have a literal `null` and a `"null"` string. There's no way to tell out. Thus I suggest you let the console print variables as-is:

```
console.log("ShowMoveItems() : ", $.cookie('selectedmoveitems'));
```

... or (if your console uses a Firebug-compatible API):

```
console.log("ShowMoveItems() : %o ", $.cookie('selectedmoveitems'));
```

Also, the `===` operator has [lower precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the `+` (addition) one, thus this:

```
"ShowMoveItems() ISNULL : " + $.cookie('selectedmoveitems') === null
```

... equals this:

```
("ShowMoveItems() ISNULL : " + $.cookie('selectedmoveitems')) === null
```

... which is obviously `false` no matter what `$.cookie()` returns.

Comment: Interesting. This is something I'll definitely remember for future debugging. What you said is showing in the update I posted. This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript also helps. (It's what I was testing for in the first place)